# Why string.pack pack integer with 4 bytes?

Tags: lua

As we all known, in standard Lua 5.4, a integer has 64 bits (8 bytes).

But `string.packsize('i') == 4`, that is to say a integer will be pack into 4 * 8 = 32 bits. It's strange, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for noise, it's because the "int" here refering is a native-sized int, as [reference](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.2) mentioned.

And in the standard C, the size of int is 32 bits (4 bytes).

Comment: In "standard" C, `int` is *at least* 2 bytes, so, theoretically, if you compiled Lua on other systems, you may find it being 2, 4 or even 8 bytes. As for *why* the default does not reflect what Lua uses, I would assume that Lua's integer size is enough an implementation detail for that, plus `string.pack` is there to serialize data for other platforms and programming languages. Of course the C compiler's `int` size is also an implementation detail, so I'd argue it's best not to use plain `i` without a size.